# changing multiple images using onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have three different images: red1, green1, and blue1. When I click red1, I want it to change to an image called red2. Then, if I click green1, I want green1 to change to green2 and red2 to change back to red1. And so forth...that's the logic.

I found some code that looks like it can be the foundation of what I want to accomplish, but I can't figure out how to modify the code. I'm not a coder...just trying to figure this out as I go along. Can anyone help? Here's the code:

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var prevSquare;

function swapImage( thisSquare )
{
if( prevSquare && prevSquare != thisSquare )
{

// Alter prevSquare image (if prevSquare is an <img> element)
prevSquare.src='images/red1.png';
}

// Alter thisSquare to your active image
thisSquare.src = 'images/green1.png';

// Assign value to previos square
prevSquare = thisSquare;
}

</script>
```

html:

```
<img src="images/red1.png" onclick='swapImage( this );'</a>
<img src="images/green1.png" onclick='swapImage( this );'</a>
<img src="images/blue1.png" onclick='swapImage( this );'</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dynamic solution, you specify the image in each state on the element itself, so just read the attribute and change the source image.

By default all images are in the off state

```js
var prevSquare = null;
function swapImage( thisSquare )
{
    if( prevSquare && prevSquare != thisSquare ) {
        // Alter prevSquare image (if prevSquare is an <img> element)
        prevSquare.setAttribute("src", prevSquare.getAttribute("srcOff"));
    }

    // Alter thisSquare to your active image
    thisSquare.setAttribute("src", thisSquare.getAttribute("srcOn"));

    prevSquare = thisSquare;
}
```

```html
<img id="redSquare" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/600.png?text=+"
srcOn="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/f00.png?text=+" srcOff="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/600.png?text=+" onclick='swapImage( this );'>
<img id="greenSquare" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/060.png?text=+" srcOn="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/0f0.png?text=+" srcOff="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/060.png?text=+" onclick='swapImage( this );'>
<img id="blueSquare" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/006.png?text=+" srcOn="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/00f.png?text=+" srcOff="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/006.png?text=+" onclick='swapImage( this );'>
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use proper event handlers, then just replace the `1` with a `2` in the source of the clicked image.
You then have to iterate over the images, and do the same for the other images, but replacing any `2` with a `1` etc.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.img');

images.forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var that = this;
    that.src = that.src.replace('1','2');
    
    images.forEach(function(img2) {
      if (img2 !== that) img2.src = img2.src.replace('2','1');
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<img src="images/red1.png"   class="img" />
<img src="images/green1.png" class="img" />
<img src="images/blue1.png"  class="img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div>
        <img id="red" src="images/red1.jpg" onclick="swap(this.id);">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img id="green" src="images/green1.jpg" onclick="swap(this.id);">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function swap(argument) {
        var element = document.getElementById(argument);
        var attr_Name = element.getAttribute("src");
            attr_Name = attr_Name.split("/").pop();
        if(argument =="red"){
            if(attr_Name == "red1.jpg"){
                document.getElementById(argument).setAttribute("src", "images/red2.jpg");
            }else{
                document.getElementById(argument).setAttribute("src", "images/red1.jpg");
            }
        }
        else if(argument =="green"){
            if(attr_Name == "green1.jpg"){
                document.getElementById(argument).setAttribute("src", "images/green2.jpg");
            }else{
                document.getElementById(argument).setAttribute("src", "images/green1.jpg");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be reached by using tags for different button colors
e.g. button is red with null tag
button gets green after click if it was red before etc:

```
final ImageButton newButton;
newButton = findViewById(R.id.newButton);

newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if (newButton.getTag() == null) {
newButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
newButton.setTag("green");
}
else if (newButton.getTag() == "green") {
newButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
newButton.setTag("blue");
}
else if (newButton.getTag() == "blue") {
newButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
newButton.setTag(null);
}
}
});
```